# Django Relación One to Many, Reutilización de código

Tags: python, django, django-models

Tengo la siguiente duda, entiendo bien el uso del **foreignKey** para crear las relaciones de uno a muchos, pero tengo un problema con esto, en realidad no me permite reutilizar eficientemente el código, aquí el siguiente ejemplo de juguete: 
Imaginemos que tengo un paquete con las clases para crear un perfil de usuario

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    user  = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Direccion(models.Model):
   ruta = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Ahora la idea aquí seria agregar múltiples direcciones al nuevo usuario creado para eso debo modificar la clase Dirección de la siguiente manera:

```
class Direccion(models.Model):
    ruta = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delelte=models.CASCADE)
```

lo que me permitiría obtener y agregar direcciones al usuario por, hasta allí vamos bien. Pero el problema que tengo es el siguiente, digamos que quiero utilizar la clase Direccion para agregar esa funcionalidad a otro modelo en el sistema por ejemplo, digamos que agregamos un empleado **(en otro paquete)**.

```
class Empleado(models.Model):
    pass
```

para agregar la funcionalidad de direcciones al Empleado según este forma de representar las relaciones tendría que crear otra clase Dirección en la que modifico el campo usuario

```
class Direccion(models.Model):
    ruta = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Empleado, on_delelte=models.CASCADE)
```

en el ejemplo de juguete no se ve lo tedioso de esto por que la clase Direccion no tiene gran lógica pero si digamos que tenga muchos más campos y formularios que la utilizan esto sera un problema. Lo más lógico sería heredar la clase Dirección o que tuviera una forma de crear la relación en la clase Empleado (como un campo OneToMany o algo así) pero por ahora no se hacerlo.

Por esta razón creo que me estoy perdiendo de algo, Debe haber una buena manera de lograr mi objetivo, entonces
**¿Cómo sería la mejor manera de reutilizar el código de clases ya relacionadas con otros modelos?**

Comment: no logro entender bien que quieres... pero quisiera saber, si de casualidad la clase empleado, tiene relacion con Usuario... o con User... tambien creo que prodria ayudarte echarle in vistazo al framework de contentype https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/ porque veo que necesitas algo de relaciones polimorficas para lograr lo que quieres... o bien puedes poner que usuario sea blank y null para que puedas usarlo en varios modelos, o añadirle una clase meta con el attr abstract, para que puedas heredar de el, y añades los campos que mas se repiten

Comment: Lo que quiero es reutilizar la lógica implementada en ciertos modelos ( como Direccion ) pero cuando creo el Modelo Dirección al usar el **ForeignKey** debo especificar el modelo con el que estará relacionado. por lo que no puedo utilizar el mismo modelo **Direccion**  con otra clase por ejemplo el modelo Empleado. Se se puede hacer y estoy leyendo, creo poder hacerlo con los modelos abstractos (como mencionas). hasta ahora es lo que en conseguido que puedo utilizar para reutilizar la lógica en ciertos modelos. Pero esta forma no me agrada del todo.

Comment: hechale un vistazo a las polimorfismo, es lo que nececitas, te pasare el link de un plugin que te ayudara.... https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno, estuve leyendo un rato la documentacion de Django... antes habia trabajado un proyecto con relaciones Génericas (Polimorfismo), nunca lo he hecho con el framwork de contentTypes propiamente dicho, pero aqui te dejaré un ejemplo de que deberias hacer...

Primero te explico, las relaciones genericas, básicamente son relaciones hacia cualquier modelo, es decir, no tedrías que decir que tu modelo `Direccion` está directamente relacionado con tu modelo de `Usuario`, si no que puede en ese campo de 'usuario' cualquier otro objeto que no sea necesariamente una instancia de `Usuario`

Tendrias tu modelo de Usuario:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    """Modelo para guardar los usuarios"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

En tu modelo de Dirección:

```
 from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
 from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
 ...
 class Direccion(models.Model):
     """Modelo para guardar las direcciones, con relaciones genericas"""
     ruta = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
     object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()  # Estos nombres son por convencion, asi que mejor que los uses
     content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Con esto seria suficiente para poder guardar la direccion con cualquier modelo... un ejemplo

```
 some_object = SomeModel.objects.create(param1=param1, param2=param2)
 Direccion.objects.create(ruta='Dummy Ruta', content_object=some_object)
 # esto no fallara...
```

La parte mala, es que no puedes hacer un `.filter()` or un `.get()` a este objeto por medio de ese campo, es decir:

```
 Direccion.objects.filter(content_object=some_object) # esto fallará, por la forma como está construido el GenericForeignKey
```

Sin embargo, en tu modelo de `Usuario` puedes agregar una relacion generica adicional... quedando tu modelo de la siguiente forma

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
...
class Usuario(models.Model):
     """Modelo para guardar los usuarios"""
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     direccion = GenericRelation(Direccion, related_query_name='usuarios')
```

Con esto seria suficiente para poder hacer filtros, de la siguiente manera:

```
 ...
 usuario = Usuario.objects.create(user=request.user)
 direccion = Direccion.objects.create(ruta='Dummy Ruta', content_object=usuario)

 # al momento de hacer filtros
 Direccion.objects.filter(usuarios=usuario)
 # O
 Direccion.objects.filter(usuarios__user__email__icontains='email@test.com')
```

Espero haberte ayudado :D

Comment: Quedo atento a cualquier pregunta, duda, sugerencia, inconveniente...

Comment: está bastante clara la explicación, haré la prueba y te cuento como me fue.